# Firebase translate value / foreign key lookup

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am querying a firebase database and need to translate a user uid into email address. This would represent a foreign key in SQL. My data is structured as below.

```
{
  "notes" : {
    "-LOs0Ikx4ydM5RatREM1" : {
      "data" : {
        "dueDate" : 1561629600000,
        "title" : "First "
      },
      "members" : {
        "author" : "1212121212121212121212121212"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "1212121212121212121212121212" : {
        "name" : "Mickey M",
        "email" : "mmouse@dis.com"
    }
  }
}
```

What I wish is to first fetch "notes" and then do a lookup to get the authors email address.

```
  let notes=  []
  const now = moment().valueOf()
  const notesRef = database.ref('notes/')
  .orderByChild('data/dueDate')
  .endAt(now)
  .once('value', (snapshot) => {
    //Collect all notes
    snapshot.forEach( (data) => { 
      notes.push(data.val())
    })
  }).then( () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      //Get author email
      note= notes[i]
      const uid = (note.members) ? note.members.author : ''

      //This gets logged for every note
      console.log('note:', note.data.title, uid)

      const usersRef = database.ref(`users/${uid}/email/`)
      .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
          const email = snapshot.val()
          console.log('Author found', note.data.title, uid, email)
        }else{
          console.log('Author missing', note.data.title, uid)
        }
      })
    }
    return true
  }).catch((error) => {
    return error
  })
```

The code above does work - but I am suspecting this approach might be a anti pattern? I do not wish to make more calls to firebase than necessary.

Could this be done more efficiently?

What is the recommended way to translate a reference value / equivalent to foreign key in firebase - in this case uid into email?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works, but in the end I realised that the author email was almost never going to be updated. So I ended up using firebase realtime database triggers to push email address to notes upon create. The email cannot be read by users and is stored in its own sub-node. This eliminated the need for a database lookup.